# Transformation around points such that the Jacobian equals $0$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $n\geq 2$ be a natural number. Consider the transformation $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow$ defined by

$$f(x_{1},...,x_{n})=\left ( \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i},\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2},...,\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{n} \right ).$$

The Jacobian for every $(x_{1},...,x_{n})\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is $n!\det(V)$, where $V$ is the $n\times n$ Vandermonde Matrix.

What conditions must the points $(x_{1},...,x_{n})\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ satisfy so that the Jacobian is different than zero and what can be said about $f$ around these points?

**Attempt:**

Clearly, if $x_{i}=0$ for every $i=1,...,n$, the Jacobian will be $0$. So the vector $(x_{1},...,x_{n})$ must be different than the origin.

Considering the definition of Vandermonde determinant, $x_{j}$ must be different than $x_{i}$ for every factor of the determinant. Otherwise, if $x_{j}=x_{i}$ for some factor, then the Jacobian will be $0$.

An obvious condition would be that the points in $(x_{1},...,x_{n})$ must not be all equal.

What I din't understand is what the question means by "what can be said about $f$ around these points?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're question is a bit vague, I'm sure many things can be said about $f$ at those points but given the context I'd say the most obvious thing to say is that you can use the inverse function theorem at the points where the jacobian is non zero.

Indeed the function $f : \mathbb R^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ is smooth so if the jacobian is non zero at $ a =(x_1,...,x_n)$ then by the inverse function theorem there is an open set $U \subset \mathbb R^n$ containing $a$ and an open set $V \subset \mathbb R^n$ containing $f(a)$ such that the restriction $f: U \rightarrow V$ of $f$ to $U$ is invertible with smooth inverse $f^{-1}: V \rightarrow U$.

Comment: I agree. It's very vague. That's why the redaction of the problem bothers me. But your answer clarifies what it means. Thank you.